# django filtering date condition

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am posting 1st job(jobname=job1) on march10, it should live from (livedate=march15) and expire on march20.

I am posting 2nd job(jobname=job2) on april15, it should live from (livedate=april20) and expire on april25

I am posting 3rd job(jobname=job3) on may20, it should live from (livedate=may25) and expire on may30.

### While filtering with "jobname" and "livedate", I have to display the jobs which should have the "livedate" greater than or equal to "today's date".

How should i write the view?

Help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//order by livedate
jobs = Job.objects.filter(livedate__gte=datetime.date.today()).order_by('livedate')

//or order by livedate with filter by job
jobs = Job.objects.filter(
           jobname=job1, 
           livedate__gte=datetime.date.today()
       ).order_by('livedate')
```

Comment: how to display the jobs which should be displayed in an order by livedate?

Comment: I thought you want only `livedate" greater than or equal to "today's date"`?

Comment: is it correct if i just want to display which is ordered by date? "jobs = Job.objects.order_by('livedate')

Comment: But when i tried this, I am getting this error, """'Manager' object has no attribute 'orderby'""

Comment: `jobs = Job.objects.all().order_by('livedate')`. you must use `filter()` or `all()` before the `order_by()`

Comment: Oh ok, and i am learning django by myself, there is noone to guide me, What is the way of effective learning? How to learn?

Answer (score 0):

The view should look something like this.
Remember that the `filter()` method will give you back a queryset and not just one object.
If you just want the one object you have to use `get()` instead of `filter()`

```
import datetime

def yourview(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(jobname="job3", livedate__gte=datetime.date.today())
    context = {'jobs': jobs}
    #render method could differ depending on what version of django you're running
    return render_to_response('template/mytemplate.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```